# Problems while creating a datalab in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-cloud-datalab

I'm getting a strange error while trying to create a datalab in GCP. gcloud is up to date, all necessary APIs are enabled. I'm following these instructions https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstart

Any ideas on what went wrong here?

[image]

Comment: This error looks like you have deleted `Compute Engine default service account`. Please go to `IAM & Admin` -> `Service Accounts` and check if you still have service account with name `Compute Engine default service account`. If it was deleted in some way you should follow instructions [Undeleting a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#undeleting). Then go to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard disable and few minutes later enable Compute Engine API and wait again. After that, you should be able to create VMs through the Cloud Shell.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem's source. I'm missing that account. I can't restore it, since looks like it have been deleted more than 30 days ago. Created a public issue. Thanks for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error looks like you've deleted in some way`Compute Engine default service account`. Please go to `IAM & Admin` -> `Service Accounts` and check if you still have service account with name `Compute Engine default service account`.

**To solve this issue** follow instructions [Undeleting a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#undeleting):

> In some cases, you can use the undelete command to undelete a deleted
>   service account. You can usually undelete a deleted service account if
>   it meets these criteria:
>
> - **The service account was deleted less than 30 days ago.**
>
>   After 30 days, Cloud IAM permanently removes the service account.
>     Google Cloud cannot recover the service account after it is
>     permanently removed, even if you file a support request.

Also, you can try to reach [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support) for further instructions.